# EJB 3 vs POJO services in JSF 2 / Seam

Tags: jsf-2, ejb-3.0, pojo

What is the difference between EJB 3 services & POJO services? Now that EJB is light & easy to develop with and works well with JPA ?

1) Benefits
2) Performace

Both have EntityManager injected in them

Any links to performace results with EJB & POJO services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EJB3 session beans can be considered POJOs these days.

If you use XML to enable services on them, they basically pass every POJO definition out there. If you use annotations, they pass the weaker definition of being a POJO.

A major difference with other frameworks that enhance POJOs with services (like CDI) is that in CDI services can be applied more fined grained. With EJB session beans, one single annotation gives you a lot of services in one go. The medium to long term plan seems to be to retrofit EJB as a collection of CDI services ( http://java.net/jira/browse/EJB_SPEC-26 is a prime example of this, with specific examples such as http://java.net/jira/browse/EJB_SPEC-1 ).

On the other hand, if with "POJO services" you mean classes without any kind of services being applied to them by a framework (EJB, CDI, Spring, etc), then the answer is that those services being added by the framework are general things that you otherwise would have to implement yourself.

You will be either building your own framework that does the exact same thing, but possibly not as good since you are not likely to work on just that framework with a whole team, OR you are implementing those concerns again and again in your services. This will clutter them, make them more verbose and probably means you will copy/paste them over and over again.

Comment: I think I need to look at CDI for handling EJB & managed beans.

Comment: Man, I would love to see this CDI+services way standardised... :-)

Answer (score 0):

EJBs have free transactions, lifecycle, and interceptors, whereas POJOs don't.